# Find the Fenchel transform of a function of two variables when one variable is fixed

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f: R^2 \to (-\infty;+\infty]$

a function of two variables $(x,y)$.

Let $f^*(u,v) = \sup_{x,y}(xu + yv)$ be its Fenchel transform.

Find the Fenchel transform $f(x,y_0)$ when fixing $y=y_0$ as for a function of one variable $x$.

There is an idea to use the formula for $(f + g)^*$ and divide the original function of two variables into auxiliary functions $f_1 (x, y_0)$ and $f_2 (x_0,y)$ with one fixed variable, but I haven’t figured out how to proceed further and bring the problem to response.

Comment: Please use tex markdown.

Comment: Connection between $X \in R^2, Y \in R^2$ and  $x \in R, y \in R$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I've edited the task, hope now it's clearer

Comment: I have attempted to improve your text using latex. Please have a look at it for next time (and check it).